# jQuery Animation and Classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assume you have a list item, `<li id="foo">` which you want to fade from one color to another when moused over, and that you are using jQuery. This is fairly easy:

```
$('li#foo').bind('mouseenter' , function(e) { 
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#F00'} , 300); 
});
```

**However, what if you wanted to get the resulting color or other style rules from a class defined in CSS without also declaring them in JavaScript?** It seems there's no way to learn style information from CSS rules without having an example of the rule already in the document, which would require you to animate the `<li>` to the target appearance, then in the animation-finished callback, set the class which leads to redundant style declarations and can foul up your CSS at "runtime".

Sorry if this question's unclear: It doesn't occur in the context of any specific project, I'm just curious how you'd go about this. Also, I know CSS3 hypothetically includes support for such transitions but using CSS for dynamic behavior like this seems such an ugly hack.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken by your question, can't you get the value like: $('li#foo').css('backgroundColor');

Comment: After you change it, but if you want to animate to the new color, no you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure javascript can't read your style-sheet.

If you want a certain property from the style-sheet that does not occur anywhere on the page, you will have to add an invisible element that has that style applied, either at page-load time in the html or with javascript whenever you want.

It does seem a bit theoretical though, instead of defining styles in your style-sheet that you are not using, you might as well declare the appropriate variable directly in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need the **[color plugin to animate background color](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)**.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply do:

```
$(this).css('background-color')
```

If you want to get the color AFTER its been updated, add it to the callback, like:

```
$('li#foo').bind('mouseenter' , function(e) { 
   $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#F00'} , 300,function(){
      alert($(this).css('background-color'));
   }); 
});
```

You can then save that to a var, or do whatever you wanted to do with it. You could also change your "bind" to "live" and it will update automatically each time its run:

```
$(selector).live(event,function(){
   alert($(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

As a side note, you shouldnt do li#foo :) just do #foo speeds up your selection time and its unnecessary as there is only 1 element with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around a little with Calvin's idea, and this is what I got:

Assuming the following CSS:

```
#somediv .bar em {
    color: #080;
}
```

You can create the elements virtually and get the style information that way:

```
$('<div id="somediv"><span class="bar"><em>')
    .find('em').css('color')
```

[Watch it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/zw6ZA/).